# Rijndael Encryption/Decryption C# to PHP conversion

Tags: c#, php, encryption

I have an encryption decryption class written in C# and i need help writing same algorithm in PHP to obtain same output result, any help finding a reliable solution is highly appreciated, Thank you.

---

> C# Code: (Input: admin, Output: nRy/sK5Z7ENvGsSwfcmLzw==)

```cs
static readonly string PasswordHash = "P@@Sw0rd";
static readonly string SaltKey = "S@LT&KEY";
static readonly string VIKey = "@1B2c3D4e5F6g7H8";

//for encrypt

public string Encrypt(string plainText)
{
    byte[] plainTextBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(plainText);

    byte[] keyBytes = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(PasswordHash,Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(SaltKey)).GetBytes(256 / 8);
    var symmetricKey = new RijndaelManaged() { Mode = CipherMode.CBC, Padding = PaddingMode.Zeros };
    var encryptor = symmetricKey.CreateEncryptor(keyBytes, Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(VIKey));
    byte[] cipherTextBytes;

    using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        using (var cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(memoryStream, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
        {
            cryptoStream.Write(plainTextBytes, 0, plainTextBytes.Length);
            cryptoStream.FlushFinalBlock();
            cipherTextBytes = memoryStream.ToArray();
            cryptoStream.Close();
        }
        memoryStream.Close();
    }
    return Convert.ToBase64String(cipherTextBytes);
}

//to decrypt

public string Decrypt(string encryptedText)
{
    byte[] cipherTextBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(encryptedText);
    byte[] keyBytes = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(PasswordHash, Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(SaltKey)).GetBytes(256 / 8);
    var symmetricKey = new RijndaelManaged() { Mode = CipherMode.CBC, Padding = PaddingMode.None };

    var decryptor = symmetricKey.CreateDecryptor(keyBytes, Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(VIKey));
    var memoryStream = new MemoryStream(cipherTextBytes);
    var cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(memoryStream, decryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Read);
    byte[] plainTextBytes = new byte[cipherTextBytes.Length];

    int decryptedByteCount = cryptoStream.Read(plainTextBytes, 0, plainTextBytes.Length);
    memoryStream.Close();
    cryptoStream.Close();
    return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(plainTextBytes, 0, decryptedByteCount).TrimEnd("\0".ToCharArray());
}
```

---

> PHP Code: (Input: admin, Output: LCvAt7BMJcG81a3foyMh8Q==)

```php
$ciphertext_b64 = "";
$plaintext = "admin";
$password = "P@@Sw0rd";
$salt = "S@LT&KEY";
$iv = "@1B2c3D4e5F6g7H8";
$iterations = 1000;
$keyLength = 32;

$prepared_key = openssl_pbkdf2($password, $salt, $keyLength, $iterations, "sha256");

$ciphertext_b64 = base64_encode(openssl_encrypt($plaintext,"AES-256-CBC",$prepared_key,OPENSSL_RAW_DATA, $iv));
echo $ciphertext_b64 . "<br/>";

$plaintext = openssl_decrypt(base64_decode($ciphertext_b64),"AES-256-CBC",   $prepared_key,OPENSSL_RAW_DATA, $iv);
echo $plaintext . "<br/>";
```

Comment: Both codes use different digests regarding the KDF (C#: PBKDF2 with HMAC/SHA1, PHP: PBKDF2 with HMAC/SHA256) and different paddings (C#: Zero Padding for encryption and no padding for decryption, PHP: PKCS#7 Padding). This causes the incompatibilities.

Comment: Please can you help with any solution to achieve this, am new to cryptography,thank you

Comment: S. here: https://paiza.io/projects/qcRuZYefKVe2hvqk134wIQ

Comment: What debugging details are needed? There is a C# code to be ported, a ported PHP code and test data for both (and that already from the beginning).

Comment: Does that mean if you encode in C# you can't use PHP to decode? @Topaco

Comment: @TranQuocBao - Actually, I don't understand your conclusion. In the third comment you even find a link with a PHP code that is compatible with the C# code.